# Check if user belongs to group via Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

Say I have a userID, and that user is logged in in my FB application, and I also have the group id.

I'm writing a JS frontend application, and can't find a simple way to confirm if the user belongs to the group.

Many thanks.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393045/facebook-graph-api-check-if-user-is-a-member-of-a-group-using-php) explains how to do it in php. The details of how to use the API are mentioned in detail

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible anymore, because the `user_groups` permission is deprecated. You can only get access to groups you manage with `user_managed_groups`, but i you manage a groupd, you are definitely a member too ;)

Although, you could do it with a group you manage, by using your own User Access Token with `user_managed_groups` and the [/group-id/members](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group/members) endpoint. But there is another problem: You may not get the App Scoped IDs, so you can´t really compare the User IDs.

Comment: Thanks, @luschn.
Yes, I was reluctantly doing it with /group-id/members. Not good :)